# How to model structured parameters in Tensorflow Probability distributions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

I'd like to model a multivariate distribution with structured parameters, for example: a multivariate normal with a covariance matrix made up of a low-rank part and a diagonal part. What is the recommended way to achieve this? (Tensorflow 2.8)

```py
DIM=4
mean = tf.Variable(np.zeros(DIM), dtype=tf.float32, name='mean')
low_rank = tf.Variable(np.zeros((DIM, 2)), dtype=tf.float32, name='cov')
diagonal = tf.Variable(np.zeros(DIM), dtype=tf.float32, name='noise')

target_distribution = tfd.MultivariateNormalTriL(
     loc=mean,
     scale_tril=tf.linalg.cholesky(
         tf.linalg.matmul(low_rank, low_rank, transpose_b=True) + tf.linalg.diag(tf.math.softplus(diagonal))
     )
)

print(target_distribution.trainable_variables)
```

returns only
`(<tf.Variable 'mean:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>,)`, i.e. only those variables assigned directly enter the realm of tracked variables, not those that enter via an expression.

What is the syntax so `low_rank` and `diagonal` become trainable variables that I can fit to data?

I realize that there is `tfd.MultivariateNormalDiagPlusLowRank` that solves this specific example, but I'm still interested in the recommended way to model structured parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run any TF op on a tf.Variable (in eager mode), the Variable value is read into a Tensor and the new value is computed, losing any previous association with the Variable. So in your example, the cholesky and matmul are all happening before the Distribution is constructed, and it never sees those Variables.

In TFP, we created a few utilities for working around this kind of issue, in particular [`tfp.util.DeferredTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/util/DeferredTensor), [`tfp.util.TransformedVariable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/util/TransformedVariable), and [`tfp.experimental.util.DeferredModule`](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/experimental/util/DeferredModule). Each of these aim to allow for lazy evaluation/construction of some thing. `TransformedVariable` is nice because it also handles updating of the underlying variable in pre-transform space. It's limited in the sense that it can only have a single underlying Variable -- your example suggests you'll want to have several floating around. Check out the examples in DeferredModule -- it might get you what you want. You may want to parameterize some composition of [`tf.linalg.LinearOperator`s])https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/LinearOperator) with some variables or something like that.

Here's your above example rewritten w/ DeferredModule: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DRX_Jv58abfsWE6h1BIz6YiQRAzCmn8r

Comment: Thanks again for this answer that clears my confusion a bit. In particular, as I noticed on closer inspection that `MultivariateNormalDiagPlusLowRank` does _not_ in fact provide a structured _covariance_ matrix as desired in the question, but a structured _scale_ matrix, i.e. the matrix root of the covariance.

Comment: If a structured _covariance_ is needed, there exists `MultivariateNormalDiagPlusLowRankCovariance` as per one of the latest releases of tfp.

Comment: Yeah historically we tried pretty hard not to introduce distributions that "hide" a cholesky factorization, so (almost) all the MVNs were scale-parameterized. IIRC MVNDiagPlusLowRankCovariance is at least able to take advantage of the known structure of the covariance to do more efficient solves (via Sherman-Woodbury or something like that).